# How to set external page link for widget click in Zerif lite wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, themes

In the focus section, when we add images to widget , I'm unable to set an external link to any other page, outside the directory, because the Zerif lite theme is a single page theme. I want to have different layout designs for different section pages.

For example:

```
parent site -> add widget -> set link (www.xyz.com)
on click of widget -> page opens -> www.parentsite.com/www.xyz.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to enter http:// or https:// in front of the link?
Like http://www.example.com/